# Altium Design Rules: Short-Circuit and Clearance

Tags: altium, design-rules

I am using an older version of Altium (14.1) and I cannot stop the short-circuit errors from being flagged.

I am trying to route an eMMC BGA that has many pads that are NC (internally not electrically connected) and I need to trace over some of them to escape the signal. When I try to use interactive routing, unless I use the Ignore Obstacles mode, I cannot trace over them. That is not the main issue however.

***My main issue is how do I get the rules check to ignore the short-circuit errors and/or the clearance violations that I am getting?*** I do not know which rule to set nor how to setup the query to properly handle this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running traces over NC pins is still very poor practice, and I do not recommend doing this. It would be VERY unprofessional. I suggest finding a way to avoid the pads, even if it means adding another layer to your board and putting in some vias. That would be the *correct* way to do it.

That being said, if you absolutely MUST trace over pads, you will need to add the NC pins to the schematic symbol and in the schematic assign them the same net as the track that you intend to lay over them. They will appear in the PCB design as a required connection point, so select your nets and place the tracks wisely.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I realize that it is not the best practice to trace over other pads but if the space between the pads are too small to put vias between them, this is really the only option. That being said, I discovered that I can individually change the nets of the individual pads of the component itself on the PrjPCB without having the connections on the schematic. But, this will not help track the original pad. Is there a way to do the same thing but by setting up the rules proper?

Comment: You can change the nets of the pads themselves in the PCB editor, yes, but then you will get errors indicating the PCB does not match the schematic. In my answer I told you how to make it work without throwing errors.

Comment: If all else fails, I will definitely change the schematic symbol to connect the pins I need to overlap to the net it uses because I do not really like to see any errors. However, is there a way to set a rule to do the same thing? I have made some pretty creative rules but I cannot seem to find the correct language to get this design rule issue to comply.

Comment: You would have to get impractically specific with the query. Just change the schematic.

Comment: I do not mind getting impractically specific with the query. As I said, I have done things like that before. I just do not know what to put in the query nor which rules I would need to query to get it to work. Does anyone have any idea as to what to put in the query to make this work via design rules?

Comment: What exactly do you have against doing things *the right way*?

Comment: I do not have anything against doing it "_the right way_" but I have a BGA with 153 balls with over 100 of them that are NC. I would rather have a rule that prevents the error than having a schematic symbol that has a lot of unnecessary no connect pins. I can possibly simplify the query with a pad class but again, I do not know how to word the query nor which design rules in which to make the query. If you do not know the answer, that is okay. I am wanting to try to do it by rule design. As I said, if it is impossible, I will have to go it the other way.

Comment: Make sure "Ignore Obstacles" is selected in the "Current Mode" dropdown under `DXP Preferences -> PCB Editor -> Interactive Routing -> Routing Conflict Resolution`. Create a "ShortCircuit" rule in the Design Rules with `HasFootprint('<your BGA footprint name>')` in the "Where The First Object Matches" field (Custom Query). Then check the "Allow Short Circuit" box and you're set. Only problem with this option is it would allow *any* short circuits to *any* pads, so like I said before, place your tracks carefully. This is probably the easiest solution you'll get to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @DerStrom8. The query did the trick. I appreciate your help. I always use grids to make sure there is extreme precision when I lay out boards. The grid is in such a way that the traces will not touch the other pads going on diagonals. The BGA I am routing does not allow enough space between the pads for a via with enough clearance. That is why going through the other pads is necessary. I do not understand why the JEDEC would design a layout the way they did. Put them all on the outside and this would not be an issue. eMMC 5.0 is the JEDEC standard.

Comment: Usually BGA devices have very low voltage and low current signals which means traces can be tiny (0.1mm). In the industry we use what are called "micro-vias", which are miniature vias designed to fit between the pads and mate with the tiny tracks. However, when it comes to hobby-level or basic production-level parts adding micro-vias can add significant cost to your board and limit you only to suppliers that can fabricate these tiny features with strict tolerances. It can become prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 1):

check on the clearnce data , change it to 0.2mm might work